# Could not proxy request from localhost:3000 to localhost:7000 ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I provided an api to my react app, it was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working.
in my client (React app) package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:7000"
```

now it tell me this error message:
Could not proxy request /api/users/signup from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:7000.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you created a socket and didn't free the port afterwards ? This may happen if your app crashes. When you launch it again, the port may be occupied and unavailable, it happened to me a few times.

Comment: I tried changing ports on both server and client, and I checked netstat and no process was running on the sme ports :\.